# Bootstrap col-auto extending beyond row size

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4

i've been struggling with this problem for the past two days. I have a web dashboard which displays charts or table on cards. These cards may have different size depending on which chart or table is rendered inside it. They are inside bootstrap nav tab content.

When i use a defined col size, such as `col-md-3` or `col-sm-4` or even only `col` evertyhing works just fine. However, when using col-auto, it "overflows" horizontally beyond the screen, row and even the container.

Below is the presentation code i removed from my angular app

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Bootstrap grid problem</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0" id="tabMenu" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item mr-1" *ngFor="let route of routeLinks; let i = index;">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" (click)="activeLinkIndex = i" [ngClass]="{ 'active': activeLinkIndex === i, 'text-light': activeLinkIndex !== i, 'bg-azul-escuro': activeLinkIndex !== i,
                    'bg-cinza-claro': activeLinkIndex === i, 'text-azul-escuro': activeLinkIndex === i, 
                    'font-weight-bold': activeLinkIndex === i }" [routerLink]="route.link">{{route.title}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content" id="tabMainContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="central" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="central-tab">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                  <ol class="breadcrumb m-0 bg-light rounded-0 ">
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faHome" class="mr-2 text-dark"></fa-icon>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Main</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Consolidated</li>
                  </ol>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row bg-light py-3 rounded-top text-white">
              <div class="col-auto bg-dark">
                <div class="mx-3">
                  <p>
                    Auto-layout for flexbox grid columns also means you can set the width of one column and have the sibling columns automatically resize around it. You may use predefined grid classes (as shown below), grid mixins, or inline widths. Note that the other columns
                    will resize no matter the width of the center column.
                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col bg-dark">
                <div class="mx-3">
                  <p>
                    Auto-layout for flexbox grid columns also means you can set the width of one column and have the sibling columns automatically resize around it. You may use predefined grid classes (as shown below), grid mixins, or inline widths. Note that the other columns
                    will resize no matter the width of the center column.
                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col bg-dark">
                <div class="mx-3">
                  <p>
                    Auto-layout for flexbox grid columns also means you can set the width of one column and have the sibling columns automatically resize around it. You may use predefined grid classes (as shown below), grid mixins, or inline widths. Note that the other columns
                    will resize no matter the width of the center column.
                  </p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `col-auto` have 0 shrink, for that its create problem

Comment: But shouldn't it be restricted to the width of the col?